# Fastest way to set class from a list of class based on some criterian in VB.net

Tags: list, vb.net, class, settings

I have a class named as "FirstNode" as clsElement0D. Now I have a list of clsElement0D having name "AllNodes". Now i want to set "FirstNode" based on some criteria from "AllNodes". Currently i am using the following method but its very slow. Because I have hundred of thousands of FirstNode and it ends up taking a lot of time.

```
If AllNodes.Exists(Function(n As clsElement0D) n.Tag = nodeNo And Not n.isModeledNode) Then
     FirstNode = AllNodes.Find(Function(n As clsElement0D) n.Tag = nodeNo And Not n.isModeledNode).ShallowCopy
End If
```

Is there any other faster method than this to do so?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you not just do the Find and then code against a null found result instead of doing the Exists AND the Find?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Yeah I can do , but it still taking a lot of time when i have thousands of such FirstNodes and i have to call this for each. So instead of find i want something different which is more faster than this.

Comment: Can you build a list of only "not n.ismodelednode" nodes beforehand? Or possibly something in parallel programming: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/

Comment: @AndrewMortimer May be one example would be helpful in this regard related to parallel programming